# Is there a typical use case that must use `is_detected_v`?

Tags: c++, standards, language-design, c++17, type-traits

Below is excerpted from [cppref](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected):

```
#include <experimental/type_traits>

template<class T>
using copy_assign_t = decltype(std::declval<T&>() = std::declval<const T&>());

struct Meow { };

using namespace std::experimental;

int main()
{
    static_assert(is_detected_v<copy_assign_t, Meow>,
        "Meow should be copy assignable!"); // version 1

    static_assert(is_copy_assignable_v<Meow>,
        "Meow should be copy assignable!"); // version 2
}
```

**Is there any difference between `version 1` and `version 2`?**

**Is there a typical use case that must use `is_detected_v`?**

Comment: The use case for this is SFINAE, not hard errors. If you want a hard error, the more direct solution is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::is_detected` can be used as a building block for `std::is_copy_assignable`. If you want to check for copy-assignability, you should use `std::is_copy_assignable`. If you need to check for the existence of a custom operation/member function, `std::is_detected` gives you an easy way of doing that.

```
template<class T>
using foo_detector = decltype(std::declval<T&>().foo());

static_assert(!is_detected_v<foo_detector, Meow>, "Meow shouldn't have `.foo()`!");
```

---

A realistic example use case is unification of different APIs:

```
template<class T>
using clean_detector = decltype(std::declval<T&>().clean());

template<class T>
using clear_detector = decltype(std::declval<T&>().clear());

template <typename T>
auto clear(const T& x) -> std::enable_if_t<is_detected_v<has_clean, T>>
{
    x.clean();
}

template <typename T>
auto clear(const T& x) -> std::enable_if_t<is_detected_v<has_clear, T>>
{
    x.clear();
}
```

Usage example:

```
struct Foo { void clean(); };
struct Bar { void clear(); };

int main()
{
    Foo f; Bar b;
    clear(f);
    clear(b);
}
```

Comment: `clean_detector` should be `has_clean` and `clear_detector` should be `has_clear` or vice versa ??

Answer (score 0):

Is detected lets you determine if a substitution would cause failure.

This lets you write a trait (ad hoc or not) that expresses a SFINAE check.

Such traits can be passed around, used as tags, and inverted.

So I can write `can_foo` easily with it.  Then I can have two overloads, one if `can_foo` the other if `!can_foo`.

With traditional SFINAE, writing an overload that is valid if `can_foo` is easy; but `!can_foo` is hard.

We can also tag dispatch or use it for constexpr if calculation.

```
auto distance( Iterator A, Sentinal B ){
  if constexpr (can_subtract_v<Sentinal&, Iterator&>){
    return B-A;
  } else {
    // count manually
  }
}
```